# How to read XML file in Xtext generator.xtend

Tags: eclipse, xtext, xtend

I am new to Xtext. 
I want to produce ouptput in generator.xtend based on xml configuration file. 
My goal is to have the same grammar, but based on xml configuration file I want to produce different output in generator. 
Can I get some advice?

Comment: Some questions to make the question more specific: where does the config xml reside. is this a question about Xtend or would you have the same problem if the generator were written in Java?

Comment: Hi @ChristianDietrich thank you for your comment. I want to configure xml file outside the DSL script. I use Eclipse Xtext environment which generate generator.xtend file where I define parsing rules. For example if I have command create.task in grammar definition, I want to translate that command in two specific languages, LAN1 and LAN2. How can I decide which language is output?

Comment: again the question is: where is the config located. how is the config file found? does it e.g. reside next to the demo.mydsl file?

Comment: Hi @ChristianDietrich. I really don't know where I can place this file and read it. I solved this problem with new rule in grammar file which contains configuration with language output. Thank you for your comments and time.

Comment: the filesystem access in the generator allows you to read files via `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IFileSystemAccessExtension3.readTextFile(String, String)`